# Google Cloud Storage using Node.js uploads only part of a file

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm using Google Cloud platform storage to upload files to the storage, but it seems most files are only uploaded half way.

The files I upload are all photos and when viewing most of the photos, it would only show part of the image. Comparing the local photos to the photos stored in GCP Storage would show a real discrepancy in size (in favor of local photos of course)

The code I'm using is very straighforward:

```
storage
  .bucket(bucketName)
  .upload(filename, { resumable: true })
  .then(() => {
    console.log(`${filename} uploaded to ${bucketName}.`);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('GCP UPLOAD ERROR:', err);
  });
```

I've tried using `resumable : true/false`, both would do the same effect.

Any ideas what's going on?

**EDIT**:

File size varies between 50Kb to 250kb. Mostly up to 70-80kb it would upload just fine, above that - it would stop at around 120-150kb (missing the other part of the file).

Comment: Can't figure why looking at the source https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/blob/master/src/bucket.js#L2322 but maybe try setting resumable as well as contentLength in the options. It seems relevant to the outbound stream. I would also try debugging their code, maybe log when the read stream says it is done, and see how far along it is.

Comment: tried everything... didn't help. setting content-length also didn't improve (but setting it too low, results in even smaller uploads)

Comment: I tried that same function that you are using but I had no problems to upload files bigger than 150kb to a bucket. 
Try to implemtent the resumable upload feature[https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/resumable-upload#resumable-xml-api]
so you can get information about the upload operation that was interrupted and get the range of bytes that was not successfully uploaded.

Comment: Does your catch clause ever get called?

Comment: nope - all goes well. the upload "finishes". Moved to AWS S3 and all works fine. really wanted to use the google cloud...

Comment: @Roman, In this situation I suggest you to create a new Cloud Storage issue [ https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187243&template=0 ] with a code sample and one of the images that can't upload. This way a deeper investigation can be done.

Comment: Was facing the same issue. Turns out in my case, what was happening was that I was saving a data stream to a file from Google Drive and instantly uploading it to Cloud Storage. The upload operation was starting before the stream ended, resulting in partial images being uploaded. Awaiting the stream 'finish' did the trick in my case. @Roman please check if you are facing any similar issue.